# Mobile CSS boilerplate similar to the Safari Reader mode on iOS

Tags: javascript, css, ios, html

Under iOS, when you open the Safari, you can click on the reader mode to make the page look better on mobile device.

Now, I am **not** asking how to convert and filter my HTML, I have the HTML already, e.g.

```
<html>
    <body>
         <p>foo</p>
         <p>foo</p>
         <p>foo</p>     
    </body>
</html>
```

I just want to see if any existing CSS boilerplate that format my page look better on mobile device.